# Редирект в зависимости от запроса

Tags: php, .htaccess, редирект

Есть сайт на котором логика api прописана в одной большой системе, а frontend в другой. Архитектура такая

```
--api
---index.php
---.htaccess
--admin
---index.php
---.htaccess
--frontend
---index.php
---.htaccess
.htaccess
```

Теперь в зависимости от запроса нужно чтобы он редиректился туда куда надо,
пример:

```
site.com на frontend
site.com/admin на admin
site.com/api на api
```

Помогите пожалуйста настроить .htaccess файл.

Спасибо!

Comment: ответ на твой вопрос вот [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352249/rewrite-rule-if-condition-is-not-matched)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут момент в том, что нужно:

1) именно редирект

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^$ /frontend [R=301,L]
#или
RedirectMatch permanent ^$ /frontend
#---
RewriteRule ^admin(/(.*))?$ /new-admin$1 [R=301,L]
#или
RedirectMatch permanent ^/admin(/(.*))?$ /new-admin$1
```

2) возможность находясь на одном адресе получать информацию с другого места без редиректа

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^admin(/(.*))?$ /new-admin$1 [L]
#или
RewriteRule ^admin(/(.*))?$ /myscript.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Как-то так...

П.с. и это только в качестве рабочего примера... вам еще допиливать под свои нужды